# STM32L432KC LPTIM1 CNT register always 0 and not enabling interrupts

Tags: c, timer, microcontroller, stm32cubeide

I am trying to use LPTIM1 to create interrupts on an STM32L432KC microcontroller. This is for an assignment and I can't use code generated by STM32CUBEMX. I made the function init_lptim1() to initialise the timer, however the timer does not create interrupts and the CNT register remains at 0.

I will also use TIM16 for pwm output and ideally I would want both these timers to use the LSI clock source (for lower power consumption). This is not that big a deal, but because I haven't decided on my clock source the ARR and PSC values are placeholders.

My current code for lptim1 initialisation:

```
void init_lptim1(void){
    RCC-> CSR |= 0x1UL; //Enable LSI
    while (!(RCC->CSR & 0x2UL)){}
    RCC->CCIPR |= 0x1UL << 18;//set clock source as LSI

    RCC -> APB1ENR1 |= 0x1UL << 31; //Enable LPTIM1
    LPTIM1->CR &= ~0x1UL; // disable LPtimer
    LPTIM1 -> CFGR |= 0x6UL << 9; // PSC 64
    LPTIM1 -> ARR = 25 -1; // FOR 20HZ (PSC 64)
    LPTIM1 -> IER |= 0x2UL;   // enable interuppts on arr match


    LPTIM1->CR |= 0x1UL; // enable LPtimer
        LPTIM1->CR |= 0x2UL; // enable single mode LPtimer

    while (LPTIM1 -> CNT < 4){ // this while loop to test if CNT is correct
    }

    GPIOB -> ODR |= 0x2UL; //this is an led that is not used for anything else.


    NVIC_SetPriority(LPTIM1_IRQn, 0x03); //SET PRIORITY TO MINIMUM
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(LPTIM1_IRQn);
}
```

The LED on pb1 does not turn on.

The code does not have any errors and in debugging mode all the registers seem to be correct. Maybe I'm missing something. I admit I am not 100% sure on what single/continuous mode do and if I need them. I will only use the timer to interrupt, and it is not used for any output.

The configuration of the board is, red LED -PB1, yellow LED PB5, green LED PA11, orange LED PA8, PWM PA6, red button PA9, orange button PB4, green button PB7

The full code is:

```
#include <stm32l432xx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<time.h>

void init_gpio(void);
void init_tim16(void);
void init_lptim1(void);
static inline void reset(void);
static inline void set(void);
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void); // green button exti handler
void LPTIM1_IRQHandler(void);
void EXTI4_IRQHandler(void);
static inline void green_pressed(void);
static inline void blinking_yellow(void);
static inline void post_T1(void);
static inline void post_T2_fail(void);
void orange_pressed(void);
void celebrate(void);
void init_lptim1(void);


// configuring AS PB7 green button and pb4 orange button !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

//configure LSI as clock source!! hopefully for both lptim1 or choose another for both.



uint8_t T1;
volatile uint8_t T2;
uint8_t T3;
volatile uint8_t win_counter=0;
volatile uint32_t lp_counter = 0; //timer for lptim
volatile uint8_t LP_mode = 0;



int main (void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    T1 = ((rand() % (26))+1);
    T2 = ((rand() % (10))+ 1);
    T3 = 6;

    init_gpio();
    init_lptim1();
    init_tim16();


    while(1)
    {
    }
}

void init_gpio(void){
    RCC -> AHB2ENR |= 0x3UL;    //Enable the clock for GPIO port A and port B
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN; // for interrupts on green button - exti

    //configure input/output mode
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~0x33CCUL << 10;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= 0x412UL << 12; //set gren org led and pwm
    //Pull down
    GPIOA -> PUPDR &= ~0x33CCUL << 10;
    GPIOA -> PUPDR |= 0x2UL << 18;//set red button
    GPIOA -> OSPEEDR &= ~0xC3UL << 16; //LED PIN 8 AND 11 LOW SPEED
    GPIOA -> OTYPER &= ~0x9UL << 8; //LED PUSH PULL

    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~0xFUL << 24;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= (0xEUL <<24);// In the GPIOx_AFR register, set the pin PA_6 to alternate function mode

    GPIOB -> MODER &= ~0xAF0AUL;
    GPIOB -> MODER |= 0x404UL;  //set red yellow led            // configuring AS PB7 green button and pb4 orange button !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    GPIOB -> PUPDR &= ~0xAF0AUL;
    GPIOB -> PUPDR |= 0x82UL<<8; // GREEEN org button
GPIOB -> OSPEEDR &= ~0x30CUL;//LOW SPEED red yellow led
GPIOB -> OTYPER &= ~0x22UL;//PUSH PULL LED


    //green button exti interrupts
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[1] &= ~(0xEUL << 12);
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[1] |= (0x1 << 12); // connect green button to exti interrupts
    EXTI->IMR1 |= (1 << 7);// Setup EXTI interrupts for falling input on the button pin.
    EXTI->FTSR1 &= ~(0x1UL << 7);// Disable the falling edge' trigger (button release)
    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (0x1UL << 7);// Enable the 'rising edge' trigger (button press).

    //red button exti interrupts
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[2] &= ~(0xEUL << 4);// connect green button to exti interrupts
    EXTI->IMR1 |= (1 << 9);// Setup EXTI interrupts for falling input on the button pin.
    EXTI->FTSR1 &= ~(1 << 9);// Disable the falling edge' trigger (button release)
    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1 << 9);// Enable the 'rising edge' trigger (button press).

    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0x01);// Enable the NVIC interrupt at HIGH priority value.
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);

    //orange button interrupts
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[1] &= ~(0x7UL);
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[1] |= (0x1); // connect green button to exti interrupts
    EXTI->IMR1 |= (1 << 4);// Setup EXTI interrupts for falling input on the button pin.
    EXTI->FTSR1 &= ~(1 << 4);// Disable the falling edge' trigger (button release)
    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1 << 4);// Enable the 'rising edge' trigger (button press).

    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_IRQn, 0x02);// Enable the NVIC interrupt at medium priority value.
    NVIC_DisableIRQ(EXTI4_IRQn); //disable orange interrupts
}

void init_lptim1(void){
    RCC-> CSR |= 0x1UL; //Enable LSI
    while (!(RCC->CSR & 0x2UL)){}
    RCC->CCIPR |= 0x1UL << 18;//set clock source as LSI

    RCC -> APB1ENR1 |= 0x1UL << 31; //Enable LPTIM1
    LPTIM1->CR &= ~0x1UL; // disable LPtimer
    LPTIM1 -> CFGR |= 0x6UL << 9; // PSC 64
    LPTIM1 -> ARR = 25 -1; // FOR 20HZ (PSC 64)
    LPTIM1 -> IER |= 0x2UL;   // enable interuppts on arr match


    LPTIM1->CR |= 0x1UL; // enable LPtimer
    LPTIM1->CR |= 0x2UL; // enable single mode LPtimer

    while (!(LPTIM1 -> CNT & 0x4)){
    }

    GPIOB -> ODR |= 0x2UL;


    NVIC_SetPriority(LPTIM1_IRQn, 0x03); //SET PRIORITY TO MINIMUM
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(LPTIM1_IRQn);
}

void init_tim16(void){
    RCC -> APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM16EN; // Enable tim16
    // RCC->CCIPR |= (0x1 << RCC_CCIPR_TIM16SEL_Pos); // Set TIM16 clock source = LSCO this wanted 14th bit // can solve in ioc

    TIM16 -> PSC = 4000 - 1;
    TIM16 -> ARR = 20 - 1; //need to change this THIS RESULTS IN 4hz - which is needed for 2hz blink
    TIM16 -> CNT = 0; //count starts on zero

    //capture control
    TIM16 -> CCMR1 &= ~0x7FUL;
    TIM16 -> CCMR1 |= (0x6UL << 4);
    TIM16 -> BDTR |= (0x1UL << 15); //manual output mode
    TIM16 -> CCR1 = 1;

    TIM16 -> DIER |= 0x1UL; //update interupt enable.... !!!!!!!mayvbe capcompare interuppt?????
}



static inline void set() { // need to fix this
    GPIOA -> ODR |= 0x900UL; // binary number leds on
    GPIOB -> ODR |= 0x20UL;
    lp_counter = 0;
}

static inline void reset() {
    GPIOA -> ODR &= ~(0x900UL); // all leds off
    GPIOB -> ODR &= ~(0x22UL);
}


void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void) {
    if (EXTI->PR1 & (0x1UL << 7)) { //exti routine for green button
            EXTI -> PR1 |= 0x1UL << 7;
            green_pressed();
        }

    if (EXTI->PR1 & (0x1UL << 9)) { //exti routine for red button
        EXTI -> PR1 |= 0x1UL << 9;
        LPTIM1->CR &= ~0x1UL; // disable LPtimer
        EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1 << 7);// Enable the green button 'rising edge' trigger (button press).
        reset();
    }
}


void green_pressed(void){
    set();
    LP_mode = 1;
    LPTIM1->CR |= 0x1UL; // enable LPtimer
}


void LPTIM1_IRQHandler(void) { //20Hz  // ordered in use amount
    if (LPTIM1->ISR & 0x2UL) {
        LPTIM1->ICR |= 0x2UL;// Clear the interrupt flag


        lp_counter++;

        if (LP_mode == 1){//T1 section waiting
            if (lp_counter == (T1*4)){
                post_T1();
            }
            return;
        }else if (LP_mode == 2){//bink yellow led
            if (lp_counter == (T2*20)){
                post_T2_fail();
            }
            blinking_yellow();
            return;
        }else if (LP_mode == 3){//wait T3
            if (lp_counter == (T3*4)){
                set();
                LP_mode = 1; //wait T1 again
                TIM16 -> CR1 &= ~0x1UL;//disable timer 16 for pwm
            }
            return;
        }else if (LP_mode == 4){//win, blink all
            if ((lp_counter % 5) != 0){return;} //this means a pulse of 4Hz beyond this

            if (lp_counter == (3*4)){
                reset();
                LPTIM1->CR &= ~0x1UL; // disable LPtimer
            }
            GPIOA -> ODR ^= 0x900UL; // all leds blink
            GPIOB -> ODR ^= 0x22UL;
            return;
        }else{
            lp_counter = 0;
        }
    }
}


static inline void post_T1(void){
    lp_counter = 0;
    LP_mode = 2; // flashing mode
    reset();
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_IRQn); //enable orange interrupts
}


static inline void blinking_yellow(void){
    GPIOB -> ODR ^= 0x1UL << 5; //blink yellow led
}


void EXTI4_IRQHandler(void) {//orange button only
    if (EXTI->PR1 & (0x1UL << 4)) { //exti routine for orange button
        EXTI -> PR1 |= 0x1UL << 4;
        orange_pressed();
    }
}

void orange_pressed(void){
    static uint8_t win = 0; //win initialised at 0 and keeps after function completed


    NVIC_DisableIRQ(EXTI4_IRQn); //disable orange interrupts

    if (win == 2){ //This saves wim++ from being run again
        LP_mode = 4; //flash all
        return;
    }

    win++; //win increases

    TIM16 -> CR1 |= 0x1UL;//enable timer 16 for pwm
    T2 = T2 * 0.75; //shorten T2
    LP_mode = 3; //to wait T3 while TIM16 raises and lowers pwm
}


static inline void post_T2_fail(void){
    LP_mode = 1; // go back to wait T1
    set();
 //maybe i need to turn off yellow
    NVIC_DisableIRQ(EXTI4_IRQn); //disable orange interrupts
}
```

There are other places in which lptim1 is enabled and disabled although it shouldn't get to this point. Also the rest of the code has not been tested because of this problem. My big questions are:

How do I initialise LPTIM1 properly?

How do I set TIM16 and LPTIM1 clock source to LSI? (and does this disable the default clock source it is using)

Comment: The reference manual says this about enabling peripheral clocks: "Just after enabling the clock for a peripheral, software must wait for a delay before accessing the peripheral registers....there is a 2 clock cycles delay before the clock be active" You don't have any delay, you go straight into accessing the timer. I believe in this context, it is two clock cycles of the peripheral clock, not the CPU clock.

Comment: @pmacfarlane The other timers I've used do not need this (2,7,16 definitely do not). How would I put in a delay besides this? Also the code should eventually leave the while loop after it has received access (I am sure the code to configure it is doing its job because I can see it change the register)?